# Can some other Azure role read unwiped disk data left by my role when my role Azure VM is reclaimed?

Tags: windows, security, azure, cloud

Suppose my Azure role stores some data on the VM local disk and is then terminated. The local disk was mapped onto some physical storage and so the data stored onto the local disk was written into that storage. When my role terminates the VM is reclaimed and the physical storage is also reclaimed.

Now some other role is started and its local disk happens to be mapped onto the same physical storage as was used my my role. I'm well aware [that the logical structure of the new local disk is completely rebuilt and all files possibly left by my role will just disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214350/is-azure-role-local-storage-guaranteed-to-be-inaccessible-to-an-application-that). However the physical storage underneath the newly created logical disk happens to be the same.

Specifically suppose the new role creates an empty file and then calls [SetEndOfFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to "extend" the file and then opens it for reading and reads the data currently stored on the logical disk. Unless special measures are taken in the Azure infrastructure I'm not sure this won't result in extending the file over data stored by my role and reading that data.

Is it technically possible for the new role to read the data written by my role?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no,

All I/O requests from the guest os are handled by the hypervisor, the hypervisor ensures that an insance can only access the assigned storage.

The only way to get access to data from old roles is to get physical access in the containers and grab it from there (if you ever succeed to get passed the datacenters physical security measures and into the sealed containers.) And even then it's not going to be easy as it's my understanding that logical disks do not map one-to-one to individual physical drives, but to clusters of drives, so physically your data will be dispersed across several disks as well.

Furthermore there are also offical disposal procedures in place that ensure that all data is removed from disks that are being disposed of.

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: Do you have references for the different claims? How does the distribution via physical drives and the hypervisor prevent me reading the "empty" disk of an azure instance I just allocated and looking through blocks? Unless the disk is encrypted on a per instance basis I can't see how that would work.

Comment: You simply can't read from a disk period... any read you do has to be asked to the hypervisor and it will do it on your behalf. And these reads will always be directed to the vhd's assigned to you..

Comment: This paper describes what the hypervisor does, including that it is responsible for all IO requests. http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9740388&clcid=0x409

Comment: I could not find information on the back-end storage/VHDs. Sure I/O requests go through the hypervisor to a VHD. Does the fabric controller ensure that the VHD is either expanded on demand (which would ensure that I can't read a block I have not written myself) or are the VHDs created on a zero-ed range in the allocated back-end storage? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The VHD themselves are copyed (from a datacenter level master copy) whenever the deployment is created, effectively physically overwriting the blocks they occupy. (They are also static and won't be expanded)

Comment: Currently local disks on Azure VMs are several dozen gigabytes in size and most of the space is unoccupied. Do you claim that the VHD has size totally identical to the size of the corresponding logical disk and completely overwrites the logical disk together with its future unoccupied space? That'd be very slow and I won't believe that unless it is backed by a source.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Yves and yes the answer is NO.

I would like to add more information on how virtual drives are created and used in any Windows Azure VM. As you may already know, each Role (Web or Worker) has minimum 3 virtual drives in it:

- Drive E: is application drive which is 1GB fixed size and created dynamically by FC using the Package updated by user. This drive is not designed to have any User data on it. This drive is created per user deployment so it new for every role. This drive is provided to Azure Virtual machine by FC and attached to VM during provisioning time.
- Drive D: is the OS/SYSTEM drive (about 25GB size) which is attached to the role and identical to each role depend on OS version. This is ready only drive to web role however startup task and worker role can write to it. The drive is dedicated OS drives and considered that user should not place any of their content on it.
- Drive C: is user drive in which user data is located. When you have local storage in your application the storage is created here. This drive is virtually created depend on Role VM size.

  - On a Windows Azure Host machine you can create a small VM or Extra Large VM so depend on your role size, your VM will get ~250GB C drive or 2TB C Drive and this storage is acquired from host machine.
  - On Host machine there are bunch of disks connected to provide large logical space to fulfill small to large VM size local storage requirement. When the role VM is provisioned,  depend on what kind of role VM is created on Host, a virtual HDD is created to from the total logical space and attached to VM as user drive.

When there is any Guest OS update or Azure Application Update:

- The updated happens in Drive D: through Diff image
- The update happens in Drive E: through Diff Image
- As Drive C is user drive and "Local Storage" is not directly affected by Guest update or role update however if "Local Storage - Clean on Role Recycle" property is set, the Local Storage will be clean by when role will be recycle.

So what happens when you remove your application from Azure:

- OS Drive D:/Diff drive is discarded
- Application Drive E:/Diff drive is also discarded
- User Drive C: is removed and the space is claimed back by the host machine.

  - Now When a new VM is created on Host machine a new user drive C: is created and the space is allocated from the available physical space and it could be any size from ~250GB to ~2TB depend on Role VM size.
  - Even when next time an extra-large guest VM is provisioned on host machine, which requires maximum size 2TB Virtual disk, the VHD is rebuild again from scratch. So back to back 2TB virtual disk for XLarge VM are still not same.
  - So there are no chances that your old files could be recovered from previous disk even when you use file system API you mentioned in your question above.

(Sorry for writing large post)